# How to specify an Android service label (android:label for the <service> tag) in AndroidManifest.xml? (RAD Studio, Delphi XE)

Tags: android, delphi, label, android-service, android-manifest

I created an Android app in RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin (Delphi), a service is attached to the application. When I compile the project then follow line appears in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:exported="true" android:name="com.embarcadero.services.MyService" />
```

But I need follow line:

```
<service android:exported="true" android:name="com.embarcadero.services.MyService" android:label="The service created manually" />
```

In the *Project->Options->Version info* has a property *Label* only for the host application, but not for the it's service.

Please help with your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution:

In the file *AndroidManifest.template.xml* of the host application it needs line:

```
<%services%>
```

to replace with the follow line:

```
<service android:exported="true" android:name="com.embarcadero.services.MyService" android:label="The service created manually"/>
```

If the appliaction includes some services, it needs to point them all in such a way. After that I need to recompile and to rebuild the project.

Now the information about my service displays the *android:label* property content, but not the content of *android:name* property.